# VSCode not suggesting imports for symbols in Poetry-managed path dependency

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense, python-poetry

I have two Python projects managed by Poetry, ProjectA and ProjectB, where ProjectA depends on ProjectB (using [path dependency](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#path-dependencies)). When using symbols (such as classes or variables) from external libraries such as `fastapi` or `requests`, VSCode successfully suggests most relevant imports (quick fix).

However, when I use symbols of ProjectB in ProjectA, VSCode fails to provide automatic import suggestions.

Notably, this auto-import suggestion feature functions as expected for symbols from external libraries. Can anyone shed light on why this issue may be occurring and provide guidance on resolving it effectively?

May it be related to `py.typed`? (I don't know what this is)

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix is to add the **path of ProjectB** to `"python.analysis.extraPaths"` in `settings.json`. You can add the codes like below:

```
{
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["Path/to/ProjectB"]
}
```

This allows Pylance to identify the location of Project B and provide the relevant IntelliSense.